# Issues with sc.next and sc.nextLine in java: sc.next means i cannot have multi-worded inputs; sc.nextLine consumes the first input in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

The issue is, when i use sc.nextLine in the code (in the line I marked) the for loop consumes the first input and then accepts the others. Using sc.next instead fixes this issues but I cannot accept a 2 word input which I need to. What can I do to fix both of these issues at the same time? (I am a beginner). Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Marks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students are there? ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
String[] Names = new String[n];
        int[] Marks = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
System.out.print("Enter name of student " + (i+1) + ": ");
Names[i] = sc.next(); // this line is the issue
System.out.print("Enter mark " + (i+1) +": ");
Marks[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }

    }
}
```

I have basically just tried variations on these 2 bits of code, I am a beginner so I do not know what else I can really do. Someone online said to just write a blank input to consume the new line character which I tried. The issue was that this made my Names array not actually store any values.

Comment: Many ways to solve this: get the line via `.nextLine()`, split the line (the String) on space, `" "`, and then parse the int. Or use two Scanners, one to get the line, and the second to parse the line into String and int,....